# Is systemd user folder analyzed recursively?

Tags: systemd

Is systemd user folder analyzed recursively?

Alternatively, can I organize my user service files into folders?

I made multiservice server application and I would like to put them in one folder to make it tidy.

Comment: Look at `/lib/systemd/system` and you'll have your answer

Comment: It doesn't seem like it does, I wanted to check.

Comment: Then see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Comment: In the **User Unit Search Path** section? It is not clear to me if having *~/.config/systemd/user/\** in the search path include directories are not.

Comment: Read the rest of it. A few paragraphs down it describes which directories are included in it and other search paths

Comment: Okay, I already knew the subdirectories as dependency part, I was wondering if I could just put everything in a folder instead. I guess the anwer that is no because the manual doesn't talk about that possibility.